# React-Native navigation to new screen not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to build an onPress button which will lead to a tracking screen. I can see the console log which shows its entering the code but its not navigating to that screen. The same screen on the drawer link navigates to the screen I want

```
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator, navigationOptions, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
```

trackButton() {
        return (

```
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Button
              title="Start Tracking"
              onPress={() => {
                console.log('Testing');
                /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
                const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
                  index: 0,
                  actions: [
                    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'TrackingScreen'})
                  ]
                })
                this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
              }}
            />
          </View>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

`reset` no longer belongs to `NavigationActions` with the implementation. With the release of V2, the implementation of `reset` and many other actions is handed over to `StackActions`.  so you should use `StackActions.reset({...})` Refer [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset)

Your code should look like:

```
onPress={() => {
   console.log('Testing');
   /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
   const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
   index: 0,
   actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'TrackingScreen'})
   ]
   })
   this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
}}
```